# ReactJS : callback error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I want to send my counter on my parent component but I have an error. I tried different code but none works.

I just want to send the counter and afterwards the score, if I can.

DuelTurn.JS

```
state = {
    compteur: 0
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({compteur: this.state.compteur++}, () => {
        this.props.callback(this.state.compteur)        
    })
}

handleClick(step) {
    if(step === true) {
        console.log('gagné')

    } else {
        console.log('perdu')
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="turn-player">Cest le tour de {this.props.pseudo} !</div>
            <div className="text-left">
                {this.props.data[0].pseudo} 
                <div>{this.props.firstScore}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="text-right">
                {this.props.data[1].pseudo}  
                <div>{this.props.secondScore}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="clear"></div>
            <div className="question"><div>Question :</div>La france a remporté la coupe du monde 98.</div>
            <div onclick={this.handleClick(true)} className="true">Vrai</div>
            <div onclick={this.handleClick(false)} className="false">Faux</div>
        </div>
        )
    }

}
```

DuelGame.js

```
class DuelGame extends React.Component {

state = {
    compteur: 0,
    firstUser: this.props.dataUser[0].pseudo,
    secondUser: this.props.dataUser[1].pseudo,
    firstScore: 0,
    secondScore: 0,
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

receiveCallBack = (compteur) => {
    this.setState({compteur})
    console.log(compteur)
}

userTurn() {
    if(this.state.compteur == 0 % 2) {
        return <DuelTurn key={this.state.firstUser} 
        pseudo={this.state.firstUser} 
        firstScore={this.state.firstScore} 
        secondScore={this.state.secondScore} 
        compteur={this.state.compteur} 
        data={this.props.dataUser} 
        callback={this.receiveCallback}/>
    } else {
        return <DuelTurn 
        key={this.state.secondUser} 
        pseudo={this.state.secondUser} 
        firstScore={this.state.firstScore} 
        secondScore={this.state.secondScore} 
        compteur={this.state.compteur} 
        data={this.props.dataUser} 
        callback={this.receiveCallback}/>
    }
}

render() {
     return (
        <div>{this.userTurn()}</div>
       )
    }

}
```

And my error is:

> bundle.js:36630 Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.callback is not a function

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your issue, you have defined the function as `receiveCallBack` while you are calling this as `receiveCallback` (B,b).

other than that you are getting empty data in your props, I suggest you put an extra check before rendering data. So instead of `this.props.dataUser[0]` use `this.props.dataUser && this.props.dataUser[0]` and like wise for your `this.props.dataUser[1]` use `this.props.dataUser && this.props.dataUser[1]`

same goes for your `this.props.data[0]` and `this.props.data[1]` use conditional rendering there as well.

That should make it work

Here is a working version of your code
https://codesandbox.io/s/3196py0vqq